# Go vendor folder is being ignored

Tags: go, import, dependencies, govendor

I'm using go 1.8.1 on OSX

My GOPATH is

```
/Users/alex/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.8.1/test-api:/Users/alex/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.8.1/global
```

My folder structure is as such (using gvm):

```
/Users/alex/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.8.1/test-api
├── bin
│   └── gvt
├── overlay
│   ├── bin
│   └── lib
│       └── pkgconfig
├── pkg
└── src
    └── test-go-api -> /Users/alex/code/test-go-api
        ├── glide.lock
        ├── glide.yaml
        ├── main.go
        ├── models
        │   └── state.go
        └── vendor
            ├── github.com
            ├── golang.org
            ├── google.golang.org
            └── gopkg.in
```

In my main.go, I import

```
import (
    "gopkg.in/kataras/iris.v6"
    "gopkg.in/kataras/iris.v6/adaptors/httprouter"
    "./models"
)
```

But it yells that it cannot find the dependency

```
main.go:4:2: cannot find package "gopkg.in/kataras/iris.v6" in any of:
    /Users/alex/.gvm/gos/go1.8.1/src/gopkg.in/kataras/iris.v6 (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/alex/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.8.1/test-api/src/gopkg.in/kataras/iris.v6 (from $GOPATH)
    /Users/alex/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.8.1/global/src/gopkg.in/kataras/iris.v6
main.go:5:2: cannot find package "gopkg.in/kataras/iris.v6/adaptors/httprouter" in any of:
    /Users/alex/.gvm/gos/go1.8.1/src/gopkg.in/kataras/iris.v6/adaptors/httprouter (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/alex/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.8.1/test-api/src/gopkg.in/kataras/iris.v6/adaptors/httprouter (from $GOPATH)
    /Users/alex/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.8.1/global/src/gopkg.in/kataras/iris.v6/adaptors/httprouter
```

Any reason it's ignoring the vendor folder in my project?

Comment: You can't use symlinks in your GOPATH, they are ignored by the build tool.

Comment: @JimB Thanks, that's annoying but that fixed it. Follow up question (maybe requires a different question), but can subpackages (ie models) reference the top level vendor? cause it's giving me errors.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but the [vendor directory documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Vendor_Directories) explains the discovery process.

Comment: @JimB In that example, will code in packages bar and quux be able to access packages installed in the vendor folder (ie crash/bang and baz)

Comment: Yes, `bar` and `quux` can import from `vendor/`, `bang` cannot. To clarify, there are no "subpackages" or "modules" in Go. Every package is independent, regardless of its relative location to other packages.

Comment: That's weird then. Cause I'm getting the following error:

models/state.go:4:2: cannot find package "_/Users/alex/go/src/test-go-api/vendor/github.com/jinzhu/gorm" in any of:
 /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.1/libexec/src/_/Users/alex/go/src/test-go-api/vendor/github.com/jinzhu/gorm (from $GOROOT)
        /Users/alex/go/src/_/Users/alex/go/src/test-go-api/vendor/github.com/jinzhu/gorm (from $GOPATH)

Im confused by the _ in GOPATH cause my GOPATH is set to /Users/alex/go

Comment: I'm guessing it's the "models" import. _Never_ use relative import paths.

Comment: ah that's it, thanks